# many to many linq query with like expression

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

What is the best way to do a many to many join ant the entity framework.

I have a tag class

favorite
I have a Tag class

```
[Table("tblTags")]
public class Tag
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [Key]
    [Column("fld_int_id")]
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }

    [Column("fld_str_name")]
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<DocumentUploadEntity> Documents { get; set; }
}
```

I have a documents class

```
  [Table("tblUploadDocument")]
    public class DocumentUploadEntity 
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        [Column("fld_int_ID")]
        public int ID { get; set; }


        public virtual ICollection<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
    }
```

I map them like this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<DocumentUploadEntity>()
    .HasMany(x => x.Tags)
    .WithMany(x => x.Documents)
    .Map(x =>
    {
        x.ToTable("tblUploadDocumentsTags");
        x.MapLeftKey("fld_int_document_id");
        x.MapRightKey("fld_int_tag_id");
    });
```

I want to search for any documents contain a tag name in a like expression.  If I was to do this in sql I would do this:

```
SELECT * FROM tblUploadDocument d
INNER JOIN tblUploadDocumentsTags ud
ON fld_int_document_id = d.fld_int_id
INNER JOIN tbltags t
ON ud.fld_int_tag_id = t.fld_int_id
WHERE t.fld_str_name like 'foo%';
```

Please excuse the table names and field names, this was not my doing.

How can I do this with linq and entity framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The beauty of the EF is that you can start from either side and use the navigation property to get to the other side of the `many-to-many` relationship. Behind the scenes EF will use the `link` table and necessary joins.

For instance, you can start from `DocumentUploadEntity`:

```
var documents = 
    from document in db.DocumentUploadEntities
    where document.Tags.Any(tag => tag.Name.Contains("foo"))
    select document;
```

or you can start from `Tag`:

```
var documents = 
    from tags in db.Tags
    where tag.Name.Contains("foo")
    from document in tag.Documents
    select document;
```

**UPDATE:**: As @James Dev correctly stated in the comments, the equivalent of SQL `LIKE 'foo%` is `Name.StartsWith("foo")`.

Comment: His like operator is 'foo%' so he needs a StartsWith not Contains

Answer (score 2):

```
var documents = DbContext.Tags.Where(x => x.Name.StartsWith("foo"))
                .SelectMany(y => y.Documents).ToList()
```

Comment: `Select`? What do you think is the **type** of `var documents`.

Comment: Will return List<DocumentUploadEntity>.